# getting started with cython by using cdef

Tags: python, function, cython

I dont understand how to setup and run code with cython.

I added `cdef`, `double`, etc to pertinent pieces of my code.

setup.py of course the name hello isn't being used.
[cython doc](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

**Edit**

Redefining the question to make it more of a concrete example.

I want to run this system of ODEs through Cython.  I am not sure if `double` is the best choice but the numbers are on the order of magnitudes of 10 to the 10 and are non-integer.

So I want to call this in a bigger code where `mus` is a variable defined in the script calling the module.  I have my `setup.py` file to compile the pyx file.  I am not sure with what I need to do so I can call this ode now.  Say I name the module 3bodyproblem.  I would then call it in the scipt as `import 3bodyproblem` and then do `3bodyproblem.3bodyproblem(what would this input be)'

I have be reading [intro to cython for odes](http://hplgit.github.io/teamods/cyode/cyode-sphinx/main_cyode.html) but I am not sure how to use their example with mine.  Also, if it needs to be in rk format, see the code below the first code.

**Code 1**

```
cdef deriv(double u, dt):
    cdef double u[0], u[1], u[2]                                                 
    return [u[3],
            u[4],
            u[5],
            -mus * u[0] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[1] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[2] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5]


dt = np.linspace(0.0, t12sec, t12sec)
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt, atol = 1e-13, rtol = 1e-13)
x, y, z, vx, vy, vz = u.T
```

**Code 2**

```
cdef deriv(dt, double u):
        cdef double u[0], u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4], u[5]
        return [u[3],
                u[4],
                u[5],
                -mus * u[0] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
                -mus * u[1] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
                -mus * u[2] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5]

solver = ode(deriv).set_integrator('dop853')
solver.set_initial_value(u0)
z = np.zeros(300000)


for ii in range(300000):
    z[ii] = solver.integrate(dt[ii])[0]


x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 = z.T
```

If I just try to compile code 1, cython doesn't know about the variables defined the larger `.py` file.  I want to avoid setting variables in the cython code so it can be used else where with out re compiling.  Here are the errors:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

cdef deriv(double u, dt):
    cdef double u[0], u[1], u[2]                                                 
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:7:17: 'u' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

cdef deriv(double u, dt):
    cdef double u[0], u[1], u[2]                                                 
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:7:23: 'u' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

cdef deriv(double u, dt):
    cdef double u[0], u[1], u[2]                                                 
                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:7:29: 'u' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            -mus * u[0] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[1] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[2] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5]


dt = np.linspace(0.0, t12sec, t12sec)
                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:16:28: undeclared name not builtin: t12sec

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            -mus * u[1] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[2] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5]


dt = np.linspace(0.0, t12sec, t12sec)
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt, atol = 1e-13, rtol = 1e-13)
               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:17:16: Cannot convert 'object (double, object)' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            -mus * u[1] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[2] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5]


dt = np.linspace(0.0, t12sec, t12sec)
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt, atol = 1e-13, rtol = 1e-13)
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:17:20: undeclared name not builtin: u0

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef deriv(double u, dt):
    cdef double u[0], u[1], u[2]                                                 
    return [u[3],
            u[4],
            u[5],
            -mus * u[0] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ODEcython.pyx:11:17: undeclared name not builtin: mus
building 'ODEcython' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ODEcython.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/ODEcython.o
ODEcython.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**Maybe this will help**

So I want to use the module in a file like this: (different deriv function but just ignore that the idea is the same)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

me = 5.974 * 10 ** 24  #  mass of the earth                                         
mm = 7.348 * 10 ** 22  #  mass of the moon                                          
G = 6.67259 * 10 ** -20  #  gravitational parameter                                 
re = 6378.0  #  radius of the earth in km                                           
rm = 1737.0  #  radius of the moon in km                                            
r12 = 384400.0  #  distance between the CoM of the earth and moon                   
rs = 66100.0  #  distance to the moon SOI                                           
Lambda = np.pi / 6  #  angle at arrival to SOI                                      
M = me + mm
d = 300  #  distance the spacecraft is above the Earth                              
pi1 = me / M
pi2 = mm / M
mue = 398600.0  #  gravitational parameter of earth km^3/sec^2                      
mum = G * mm  #  grav param of the moon                                             
mu = mue + mum
omega = np.sqrt(mu / r12 ** 3)
#  distance from the earth to Lambda on the SOI                                     
r1 = np.sqrt(r12 ** 2 + rs ** 2 - 2 * r12 * rs * np.cos(Lambda))
vbo = 10.85  #  velocity at burnout                                                 
h = (re + d) * vbo  #  angular momentum                                             
energy = vbo ** 2 / 2 - mue / (re + d)  #  energy                                   
v1 = np.sqrt(2.0 * (energy + mue / r1))  #  refer to the close up of moon diagram   
#  refer to diagram for angles                                                      
theta1 = np.arccos(h / (r1 * v1))
phi1 = np.arcsin(rs * np.sin(Lambda) / r1)
#                                                                                   
p = h ** 2 / mue  #  semi-latus rectum                                              
a = -mue / (2 * energy)  #  semi-major axis                                         
eccen = np.sqrt(1 - p / a)  #  eccentricity 

nu0 = 0
nu1 = np.arccos((p - r1) / (eccen * r1))


#  Solving for the eccentric anomaly                                                
def f(E0):
    return np.tan(E0 / 2) - np.sqrt((1 - eccen) / (1 + eccen)) * np.tan(0)


E0 = brentq(f, 0, 5)


def g(E1):
    return np.tan(E1 / 2) - np.sqrt((1 - eccen) / (1 + eccen)) * np.tan(nu1 / 2)


E1 = fsolve(g, 0)


#  Time of flight from r0 to SOI                                                    
deltat = (np.sqrt(a ** 3 / mue) * (E1 - eccen * np.sin(E1)
                                   - (E0 - eccen * np.sin(E0))))



#  Solve for the initial phase angle 
def s(phi0):
    return phi0 + deltat * 2 * np.pi / (27.32 * 86400) + phi1 - nu1


phi0 = fsolve(s, 0)


nu = -phi0                                                                   

gamma = 0 * np.pi / 180  #  angle in radians of the flight path                     

vx = vbo * (np.sin(gamma) * np.cos(nu) - np.cos(gamma) * np.sin(nu))
#  velocity of the bo in the x direction                                            
vy = vbo * (np.sin(gamma) * np.sin(nu) + np.cos(gamma) * np.cos(nu))
#  velocity of the bo in the y direction                                            

xrel = (re + 300.0) * np.cos(nu) - pi2 * r12


yrel = (re + 300.0) * np.sin(nu)


u0 = [xrel, yrel, 0, vx, vy, 0]


def deriv(u, dt):
    return [u[3],  #  dotu[0] = u[3]                                                
            u[4],  #  dotu[1] = u[4]                                                
            u[5],  #  dotu[2] = u[5]                                                
            (2 * omega * u[4] + omega ** 2 * u[0] - mue * (u[0] + pi2 * r12) /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum *
             (u[0] - pi1 * r12) /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
            #  dotu[3] = that                                                       
            (-2 * omega * u[3] + omega ** 2 * u[1] - mue * u[1] /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum * u[1] /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
            #  dotu[4] = that                                                       
            0]  #  dotu[5] = 0                                                      


dt = np.linspace(0.0, 259200.0, 259200.0)  #  secs to run the simulation            
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt)
x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 = u.T


fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, color = 'r')
#  adding the moon                                                                  
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
xm = rm * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)) + r12 - pi2 * r12
ym = rm * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
zm = rm * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(xm, ym, zm, color = '#696969', linewidth = 0)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000])
#  adding the earth                                                                 
xe = re * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)) - pi2 * r12
ye = re * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
ze = re * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(xe, ye, ze, color = '#4169E1', linewidth = 0)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000])

pylab.show()
```

Comment: Can you show how you compile and run the Cython code?

Comment: @Kos  I am using the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env ipython` where in my bashrc I have `alias ipython='ipython --pylab=qt'`

Comment: Shebangs don't expand shell aliases. And Cython files cannot be run directly, they must be compiled. See the Cython documentation.

Comment: @larsmans I get the same error when compiling the pyx file and I have read the documentation.

Comment: @Kos I made the question a little clearer with a concrete problem I am facing.

Comment: @larsmans I made a concrete example with the a problem.

Comment: As @Kos pointed out you have not really shown us how you are compiling the cython code or the exact error . Also ipython environment works with python I think you will have to make this function usable in python through a setup file

Comment: @dusual I am using the standard setup.py from the Cython docs.  I have added it to the op as well as the link.

Comment: how do you run the code and what is the error that you get

Comment: @dusual I haven't ran it yet because it isn't fully setup to work.  Once, I make the module, how will I pass in the time, and initial conditions?

Comment: you probably should decide if `u` is an array or not (and than properly declare it as such). Also, what is `mus`?

Comment: also, if you what do you want to be callable from python? defining `deriv` via `cdef` will make in uncallable from python

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
# hello.pyx
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

def deriv(np.ndarray u, double mus):
    return [u[3],
            u[4],
            u[5],
            -mus * u[0] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[1] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5,
            -mus * u[2] / (u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2) ** 1.5]
```

build as before, than use it in python like this:

```
import hello
[...]
u_new = hello.deriv(u, mus)  # or put it into odeint
```

`cdef` functions are only callable from the c-side, also you must put all parameters in the function definition.

Comment: mus is a constant and dt is the time.

Comment: but you are not using dt in deriv (from code1), if *mus* is a const, just put it into the function body

Comment: I want to make this module universe so any mu and dt can be passed into though.  dt will be called in the bigger file inside odeint(deriv, u0, dt)

Comment: than keep it as is, did you try to compile it?

Comment: It errors: `home/dustin/Documents/School/UVM/Engineering/OrbitalMechanics/odecython.py in <mod\
ule>()
    107 print "The initial position and velocity vectors are", u0
    108
--> 109 unew = ODEcython.deriv(u, mus)
    110
    111 dt = np.linspace(0.0, 259200.0, 259200.0)  #  secs to run the simulation

NameError: name 'u' is not defined`

Comment: If I try going into odeint, I get `/home/dustin/Documents/School/UVM/Engineering/OrbitalMechanics/odecython.py in <mod\
ule>()
    108
    109 dt = np.linspace(0.0, 259200.0, 259200.0)  #  secs to run the simulation
--> 110 unew = ODEcython.odeint(unew, u0, dt)
    111 x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 = unew.T
    112

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'odeint'`

Comment: I added an example of where I would use the module which may help. It is a different deriv but you can ignore that.